# android camera: onActivityResult() intent is null if it had extras

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

After searching a lot in all the related issues at Stack Overflow and finding nothing, please try to help me.

I created an intent for capture a picture. Then I saw different behavior at `onActivityResult()`: if I don't put any extra in the Intent (for small pics) the Intent in onActivityResult is ok, but when I put extras in the intent for writing the pic to a file, the intent in onActivityResult is `null`!

The Intent creation:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// without the following line the intent is ok
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

Why is it null, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to utilize the Uri.fromFile(f) property once you are inside of OnActivityForResult()?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It happens the same to me, if you are providing `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then the intent is null, but you will have the photo in the file you provided (`Uri.fromFile(f)`).

If you don't specify `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` then you will have an intent which contains the uri from the file where the camera has saved the photo.

Don't know if it as a bug, but it works that way.

**EDIT:** So in onActivityResult() you no longer need to check for data if null. The following worked with me:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST://actionCode
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                //For Image Gallery
            }
            return;

        case CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST://actionCode
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //For CAMERA
                //You can use image PATH that you already created its file by the intent that launched the CAMERA (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for replying. how can i give the camera path to save the pics in another way?

Comment: If you don't specify the EXTRA_OUPTUT you will have an Intent, which contains the uri of the picture, BUT it will be a thumbnail (not a full resolution one). Another way, probably will be to use the Camera API and create an instance of Camera, but I have no experience with this.

Comment: One question for you : Why do you need an intent? I mean, you have the photo in the file, isn't it enough? It is not working as expected, as the intent is null, but at least you got the photo.

Comment: cause i wanted to get the img with extras.get("data") to display it on the screen. it's easier way, no?

Comment: Once you have the file, you can show it in many different ways, for instance, create a Bitmap with Bitmap.decodeFile (you can rescale here if needed), and set in an ImageView with ImageView.setImageBitmap. Another option could be to use ImageView.setImageUri and provide a Uri of the file.

Comment: you are right, but i wanted shortcut.. anyway your comment is very useful for me and i'll use one of the ways you suggested. thanks for giving your time!

Comment: how to tell if the user cancel the camera?

Comment: Got you.. Thanks.. By the way, can you provide me the link to developer website which states that passing EXTRA_OUTPUT will return null intent in `onActivityResult()` ?

Answer (score 1):

A sample written in Kotlin. You create a `Uri` for camera app, `CameraFragment` holds it until camera returns from saving your picture and gives it back to you in `onActivityResult` as you would expect.

#### CameraFragment.kt

Acts as an intermediary between consumer and camera app. Takes `Uri` as input and returns it in data `Intent`.

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val TAG = CameraFragment::class.java.simpleName

        private val KEY_URI = ".URI"

        fun newInstance(uri: Uri, targetFragment: Fragment, requestCode: Int): CameraFragment {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putParcelable(KEY_URI, uri)
            val fragment = CameraFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            fragment.setTargetFragment(targetFragment, requestCode)
            return fragment
        }
    }

    private lateinit var uri: Uri

    private var fired = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true

        fired = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("fired") ?: false

        if (!fired) {
            val args = arguments
            uri = args.getParcelable(KEY_URI)

            val i = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            context.grantUriPermission(i, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

            startActivityForResult(i, targetRequestCode)
            fired = true
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putBoolean("fired", fired)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == targetRequestCode) {
            context.revokeUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

            val newData = Intent()
            newData.data = uri
            targetFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, newData)

            dismiss()
        }
    }

    private fun dismiss() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit()
    }
}

/** Grant Uri permissions for all camera apps. */
fun Context.grantUriPermission(intent: Intent, uri: Uri, modeFlags: Int) {
    val resolvedIntentActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (resolvedIntentInfo in resolvedIntentActivities) {
        val packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, modeFlags);
    }
}
```

#### Invoke camera intent

`this` is a fragment in your app which will trigger the camera. `RC_CAMERA` is your request code for this action.

```
val uri = /* Your output Uri. */
val f = CameraFragment.newInstance(uri, this, RC_CAMERA)
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(f, CameraFragment.TAG).commit()
```

#### Handle camera result

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when(requestCode) {
        RC_CAMERA -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val uri = data?.data
                // Do whatever you need.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data should I put in val uri = ?

Comment: Possibly a `Uri` from your [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) pointing to a private cache file.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you create the `f`for the `Uri.fromFile(f)`?

It must be a valid `File` object. Try to create it before the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` line.

```
File f = new File("valid path");
```

Try with something like this:

```
File file = new File(dataFile);
Uri outFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Comment: i created this before. i'm quit sure that the file object is valid because the pictures are saved there ok.

Comment: TAKE_PHOTO is 1888? in this way the onActivityResult() isn't invoked at all (to me..) is it invoked for you? i'm perplexed.

Comment: TAKE_PHOTO is a private variable that you should define, to pass to the method who catchs the action

Answer (score -7):

use the following:

Bitmap bitmap = data.getExtras().getParcelable("data");

it works.

Comment: getExtras() is null when you had intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));