# Android Camera Intent onActivityResult() Null error using a Developer.Android guide

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm attempting to use the basic taking photo intent to return a thumbnail and set it to an image view, as shown on the developer website:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Expect I'm getting a null object reference

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity ... java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference ... at line "mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);"

**UPDATE:** Not merely a how to fix null object question, but more importantly how `onActivityResult()` fits into the rest of the lifecycle. Why does Android forget the assignment of `mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);` in `onCreate()` and in `onResume` when `onActivityResult()` is called after a camera intent? Does `onActivityResult()` act as a separate special event within the activity lifecycle? If it does, the developer guide at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html should be updated to include that.

Comment: Your imageview is null?

Comment: where is your ImageView mImageView = findViewById(R.id.your_imageView);

Comment: Did you check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564112/android-camera-onactivityresult-intent-is-null-if-it-had-extras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `mImageView` is null, you can set reference with findViewById(R.id.idImageView);

Comment: Ah yes, I referenced it in `onCreate()`, but adding it to `onActivityResult()` seemed to do the trick. I read that error as the bitmap was null, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Cool, your crash is really not a duplicate of the dozen questions that have NPE in onActivityResult of the [android-camera-intent](/questions/tagged/android-camera-intent).

When your `onActivityResult()` callback is invoked, the **mImageView** field of your Activity is **null**. Most likely, this happens because your Activity was created anew by the system after camera fulfilled your Intent. You should put the line

```
mImageView = findViewById(R.id.your_imageView);
```

either in `onCreate()` of your Activity, or you can even do that inside `onActivityResult()`. `onResume()` is [too late](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/3epIML7fjGw/J46YefbBlGEJ). In any case, you must make sure that the appropriate **layout** is loaded.

Comment: It only appears to work when `mImageView = findViewById(R.id.your_imageView);` is called within `onActivityResult()`. Even when set in `onCreate` and `onResume` the object is null.

Comment: You are right: `onResume()` is not good in this case, `onActivityResult()` happens before.